# Powershell: Inserting XML derived from a web service call into an existing XML doc

Tags: xml, powershell, xpath

I am building an XML document using Powershell and the System.Xml.XmlTextWriter class.
I need to insert an xml node into this document. This XML node has to be sourced from a web service call.

I have been able to get the correct XML using
 `$kalSes = Invoke-RestMethod -uri $TokenUri -Method Post -Body $kstring | Select-Xml -XPath "/"`

I now need to insert this XML into a document I am constructing using
an `XMLTextWriter $XW`

```
 $XW.WriteStartElement("CustomData")
   $XW.WriteNode($kalSes,'false')
 $XW.WriteEndElement()
```

This fails with the error

> Cannot find an overload for "WriteNode" and the argument count: "2".

As the documentation on MSDN states the `WriteNode()` method expects an XmlReader object .I have tried creating an XML reader object with the `$kalSes` XML and then feeding this to the WriteNode() method.. but no joy.

```
New-Object System.Xml.XmlTextReader($kalSes)
```

> New-Object : A constructor was not found. Cannot find an appropriate constructor for type 
>   System.Xml.XmlTextReader.

I have tried writing `$kalSes` to a file and then reading it again with an XML reader & feed this to `WriteNode` It produces an error

> Invoke-RestMethod : The process cannot access the file 'PATH\xml.txt' 
>   because it is being used by another process.

I think the writing method has the file locked at the same time as the reading method is trying to read it. Even if I could get this apprach to work, I am sure it will be very slow over hundreds of input values

Finally
I have tried using the `WriteElementString(name,value)` method but this escapes the xml tags

I would appreciate any guidance your collective wisdom my bring !

Angus

AS REQUESTED by Jim Moyle
Powershell script

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Web
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Xml
# Setup some static variables
$csvpath = "{PATH}\KaltSource.csv"
$xmlpath = "{PATH}\KaltSource.xml"

# Setup Kaltura session Token retrieval
$TokenUri = "http://webkaltura.aftrs.edu.au/api_v3/index.php?service=session&action=start"
$kstring = "secret={SECRET}&type=2&partnerId={PI}"

#Setup Kaltura metadata retrieval
$metadataURI = "http://webkaltura.aftrs.edu.au/api_v3/index.php?service=metadata_metadata&action=list"


# This is a kaltura Session string this will have to be generated before the script is run and pased here 
$kalSes = Invoke-RestMethod -uri $TokenUri -Method Post -Body $kstring | Select-Xml -XPath "/xml/result"
Write-Host ($kalSes)

#setup xml document writer
$XW = New-Object System.Xml.XmlTextWriter($xmlpath,$Null) 
$XW.Formatting = "Indented"
$XW.Indentation = "4"
#XML Declaration
$XW.WriteStartDocument()

$XW.WriteStartElement("mrss")
$XW.WriteAttributeString("xmlns:xsd","http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema")
$XW.WriteAttributeString("xmlns:xsi","http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance")
$XW.WriteAttributeString("xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation","ingestion.xsd")
$XW.WriteStartElement("channel")

#Begin writing each item within loop
Import-CSV $csvpath | ForEach-Object { 
   # get the custom data from kaltura
   # Custom data is XML embedded in a XML response object. The embedded XML has been http encoded. We have to extract the desired information 
   # from the XML resonse object then http decode to get proper XML to insert into our document  

   $kstring = "ks="+$kalSes+"&filter%3AobjectIdEqual="+$_.Entity+"&filter%3AobjectType=KalturaMetadataFilter"

   $metaD = Invoke-RestMethod -uri $metadataURI -Method Post -Body $kstring | Select-Xml -XPath "/xml/result/objects/item/xml"

   $metaDstr = [System.Web.HttpUtility]::HtmlDecode($metaD)

   #create a xml reader
   # Try to insert the XML data into an XML reader object to pass to the 
   # XmlTextWriter WriteNode method
   #$XR = New-Object System.Xml.XmlTextReader($metaDstr)

   # Set the ftp path
   $ftppath = "ftp://{PRIVATE DATA}" + $_.Path
   $XW.WriteStartElement("item")

   $XW.WriteElementString("action","add")
   $XW.WriteElementString("type","1")
   $XW.WriteElementString("name",$_.name)
   $XW.WriteElementString("description",$_.description)
   # Handle media tags
   $XW.WriteStartElement("tags")
      $XW.WriteElementString("tag",$_.tags)
   $XW.WriteEndElement() #close tags

   # Handle the Categories
   $XW.WriteStartElement("categories")
      $XW.WriteElementString("category",$_.categories)
   $XW.WriteEndElement() #close categories

   $XW.WriteStartElement("media")
      $XW.WriteElementString("mediaType",$_.media_type)
   $XW.WriteEndElement() #close media

   $XW.WriteStartElement("contentAssets")
   $XW.WriteStartElement("content")
      $XW.WriteStartElement("urlContentResource")
      $XW.WriteAttributeString("url",$ftppath)
   $XW.WriteEndElement() #close content
   $XW.WriteEndElement() #close contentAssets

   $XW.WriteStartElement("customDataItems")
     $XW.WriteStartElement("customData")
     $XW.WriteAttributeString("metadataProfile","{PRIVATE DATA}")
     $XW.WriteNode($metaDstr,'false')
     $XW.WriteEndElement() # Close customData
   $XW.WriteEndElement() # Close customDataItemclear

   $XW.WriteEndElement() #close item
}

$XW.WriteEndElement() #close channel
$XW.WriteEndElement() #close mrss

$XW.WriteEndDocument()


$XW.Flush()
$XW.Close()
```

Source CSV

```
name,description,tags,categories,media_type,file,Path,Entity
Top Girls,Directed by XX,student films,Student Films,1,0_intymm19.mp4,/Media/4/269/0_gqv6w2zc_0_xxv8em29_2.mp4,0_03yxzyuy
```

XML returned from WS call

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xml>
<result>
<objectType>KalturaMetadataListResponse</objectType>
<objects>
<item>
<objectType>KalturaMetadata</objectType>
<id>159</id>
<partnerId>106</partnerId>
<metadataProfileId>1</metadataProfileId>
<metadataProfileVersion>17</metadataProfileVersion>
<metadataObjectType>1</metadataObjectType>
<objectId>0_9jf3ii26</objectId>
<version>7</version>
<createdAt>1382305441</createdAt>
<updatedAt>1421895691</updatedAt>
<status>1</status>
<xml>&lt;metadata&gt;
  &lt;LOGLINE&gt;An emotional roller-coaster that explores the inner workings of an anxious mind.&lt;/LOGLINE&gt;
  &lt;YearVideoMade&gt;2011&lt;/YearVideoMade&gt;
  &lt;LevelOfStudy&gt;Graduate Diploma&lt;/LevelOfStudy&gt;
  &lt;SYNOPSIS&gt;A handcuffed prisoner shuffles in to a dimly lit police interrogation room. He tries to talk his way out of a grim situation - bargaining, pleading until, finally becoming apoplectic, he tears his clothes off and collapses naked to the floor. Lying there, he accepts his situation... then heaves himself up and steps back outside towards his fate.&lt;/SYNOPSIS&gt;
  &lt;Director&gt;Lisa Hoppe&lt;/Director&gt;
  &lt;DirectorID&gt;19577&lt;/DirectorID&gt;
  &lt;Writer&gt;Lisa Hoppe&lt;/Writer&gt;
  &lt;WriterID&gt;19577&lt;/WriterID&gt;
  &lt;Producer&gt;Anna Slowiak&lt;/Producer&gt;
  &lt;ProducerID&gt;19084&lt;/ProducerID&gt;
  &lt;Cinematographer&gt;Emma Paine&lt;/Cinematographer&gt;
  &lt;CinematographerID&gt;18089&lt;/CinematographerID&gt;
  &lt;Editor&gt;Andrew Simmons&lt;/Editor&gt;
  &lt;EditorID&gt;19074&lt;/EditorID&gt;
  &lt;LocationSound&gt;Martin Cox&lt;/LocationSound&gt;
  &lt;LocationSoundID&gt;16638&lt;/LocationSoundID&gt;
  &lt;PostSound&gt;Andrew Simmons&lt;/PostSound&gt;
  &lt;PostSoundID&gt;19074&lt;/PostSoundID&gt;
  &lt;Composer&gt;Jenna Cave&lt;/Composer&gt;
  &lt;ComposerID&gt;19399&lt;/ComposerID&gt;
  &lt;AreaOfSpecialisation&gt;Directing&lt;/AreaOfSpecialisation&gt;
  &lt;AFTRSSTUDENTKEYCREATIVECREW&gt;Lisa Hoppe: director&lt;/AFTRSSTUDENTKEYCREATIVECREW&gt;
  &lt;AFTRSSTUDENTKEYCREATIVECREW&gt;Lisa Hoppe/Bobbie Waterman: writer&lt;/AFTRSSTUDENTKEYCREATIVECREW&gt;
  &lt;AFTRSSTUDENTKEYCREATIVECREW&gt;Anna Slowiak: producer&lt;/AFTRSSTUDENTKEYCREATIVECREW&gt;
  &lt;AFTRSSTUDENTKEYCREATIVECREW&gt;Emma Plaine: cinematographer&lt;/AFTRSSTUDENTKEYCREATIVECREW&gt;
  &lt;AFTRSSTUDENTKEYCREATIVECREW&gt;Andrew Simmons: editor&lt;/AFTRSSTUDENTKEYCREATIVECREW&gt;
  &lt;AFTRSSTUDENTKEYCREATIVECREW&gt;Vicki Nhieu: production designer&lt;/AFTRSSTUDENTKEYCREATIVECREW&gt;
  &lt;AFTRSSTUDENTKEYCREATIVECREW&gt;Martin Cox: location sound&lt;/AFTRSSTUDENTKEYCREATIVECREW&gt;
  &lt;AFTRSSTUDENTKEYCREATIVECREW&gt;Andrew Simmons: post sound&lt;/AFTRSSTUDENTKEYCREATIVECREW&gt;
  &lt;AFTRSSTUDENTKEYCREATIVECREW&gt;Jenna Cave: composer&lt;/AFTRSSTUDENTKEYCREATIVECREW&gt;
&lt;/metadata&gt;</xml>
</item>
</objects>
<totalCount>1107</totalCount>
</result>
<executionTime>0.28421306610107</executionTime>
</xml>
```

Decoded data of interest

```
<metadata>
      <LOGLINE>An emotional roller-coaster that explores the inner workings of an anxious mind.</LOGLINE>
      <YearVideoMade>2011</YearVideoMade>
      <LevelOfStudy>Graduate Diploma</LevelOfStudy>
      <SYNOPSIS>A handcuffed prisoner shuffles in to a dimly lit police interrogation room. He tries to talk his way out of a grim situation - bargaining, pleading until, finally becoming apoplectic, he tears his clothes off and collapses naked to the floor. Lying there, he accepts his situation... then heaves himself up and steps back outside towards his fate.</SYNOPSIS>
      <Director>Lisa Hoppe</Director>
      <DirectorID>19577</DirectorID>
      <Writer>Lisa Hoppe</Writer>
      <WriterID>19577</WriterID>
      <Producer>Anna Slowiak</Producer>
      <ProducerID>19084</ProducerID>
      <Cinematographer>Emma Paine</Cinematographer>
      <CinematographerID>18089</CinematographerID>
      <Editor>Andrew Simmons</Editor>
      <EditorID>19074</EditorID>
      <LocationSound>Martin Cox</LocationSound>
      <LocationSoundID>16638</LocationSoundID>
      <PostSound>Andrew Simmons</PostSound>
      <PostSoundID>19074</PostSoundID>
      <Composer>Jenna Cave</Composer>
      <ComposerID>19399</ComposerID>
      <AreaOfSpecialisation>Directing</AreaOfSpecialisation>
      <AFTRSSTUDENTKEYCREATIVECREW>Lisa Hoppe: director</AFTRSSTUDENTKEYCREATIVECREW>
      <AFTRSSTUDENTKEYCREATIVECREW>Lisa Hoppe/Bobbie Waterman: writer</AFTRSSTUDENTKEYCREATIVECREW>
      <AFTRSSTUDENTKEYCREATIVECREW>Anna Slowiak: producer</AFTRSSTUDENTKEYCREATIVECREW>
      <AFTRSSTUDENTKEYCREATIVECREW>Emma Plaine: cinematographer</AFTRSSTUDENTKEYCREATIVECREW>
      <AFTRSSTUDENTKEYCREATIVECREW>Andrew Simmons: editor</AFTRSSTUDENTKEYCREATIVECREW>
      <AFTRSSTUDENTKEYCREATIVECREW>Vicki Nhieu: production designer</AFTRSSTUDENTKEYCREATIVECREW>
      <AFTRSSTUDENTKEYCREATIVECREW>Martin Cox: location sound</AFTRSSTUDENTKEYCREATIVECREW>
      <AFTRSSTUDENTKEYCREATIVECREW>Andrew Simmons: post sound</AFTRSSTUDENTKEYCREATIVECREW>
      <AFTRSSTUDENTKEYCREATIVECREW>Jenna Cave: composer</AFTRSSTUDENTKEYCREATIVECREW>
    </metadata>
```

Comment: If you could give an example of the xml doc you are adding to and the information you are getting from the REST endpoint that would be helpful.

Comment: @JimMoyle Hi Jim thanks for your interest. I have edited the post to show the data I am trying to work with and the Powershell code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I couldn't get it working if I used your method of streaming the xml to a file, so I changed it to manipulating the xml in variables.  You could then take the end result and do what ever you like with it.

Hopefully the comments in code are enough to help you with understanding my method, if not leave a comment and I'll try and explain.

An alternative approach would be to create a custom PoSH object, manipulate that as normal and the use export-clixml to write it to disk.

There may well be better and more elegant solutions than this, but I used this question as a way to make me go away an learn more about xml manipulation.  So this is a first pass shall we say....

```
cls
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Xml

#csv details
$csvpath = "\\path\KaltSource.csv"

#create root of xml file as a here string
$baseString = 
@"
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<mrss xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="ingestion.xsd">
    <channel>
    </channel>
</mrss>
"@

#Convert string to xml
$baseXml = [xml]$baseString


#pass csv details to foreach
Import-CSV $csvpath | ForEach-Object { 

$ftpPath = "ftp://yourdomain.com" + $_.Path

#create here string xml from csv input
$csvString = 
@"
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<item> 
    <action>add</action>
    <type>1</type>
    <name>$($_.name)</name>
    <description>$($_.description)</description>
    <tags>
        <tag>$($_.tags)</tag>
    </tags>
    <categories>
        <category>$($_.categories)</category>
    </categories>
    <media>
        <mediaType>$($_.media_type)</mediaType>
    </media>
    <contentAssets>
        <content>
            <urlContentResource url="$ftppath"/>
        </content>
        <customDataItems>
            <customData metadataProfile="private data"/>
        </customDataItems>
    </contentAssets>
</item>
"@

#convert string to xml
$csvXml = [xml]$csvString

#get metadata from REST in your case, in my testing I got from a local file
$metaDstr = Get-Content "\\path\film.xml"
[xml]$metaDstr = $metaDstr

#add metadata node into the node we created from the csv input
$csvXml.item.AppendChild($csvXml.ImportNode($metaDstr.metadata, $true))

#As channel is an empty node we need to select it before adding anything into it
$node = $baseXml.mrss.SelectSingleNode("channel")

#Add all the information we've gathered into the base xml we set up at the top
$node.AppendChild($baseXml.ImportNode($csvXml.item, $true))

}
```

Comment: Just in case it's not clear your final xml is inside $baseXml

Comment: Hi @JimMoyle Thanks for your solution. I have found another solution which involved converting the data payload into an `XML node object --> XPathDocument --> XpathNavigator`.

This is then a suitable type to feed to the `XmlTextWriter.WriteNode() method`

Answer (score 0):

For the benefit of others who might find this post later, I am providing a solution that I found to the problem above. @JimMoyle has provided an very workable solution however I want to post an alternative.

From the information above the data payload I am interested in is html encoded within an XML envelope

`$payload = Invoke-RestMethod -uri $metadataURI -Method Post -Body $kstring | Select-Xml -XPath "/xml/result/objects/item/xml"`

This is returned as a string object which is html decoded and cast to an XML document.

`[xml] $metaD = [System.Web.HttpUtility]::HtmlDecode($payload)`

This XML document is then turned into an XML node

`$nodeReader = New-Object System.Xml.XmlNodeReader($metaDstr)`

XML node is made into an XPathDocument

`$XPD = New-Object System.Xml.XPath.XPathDocument($nodeReader)`

Which is constructed into an XPathnavigator

`$XPreader = $XPD.CreateNavigator()`

XPathenavigator is a suitable argument for the `XmlTextWriter.WriteNode()` method

`$XW.WriteNode($XPreader,'false')`

The hint came from 
[Rob Lang on the DZONE site](https://dzone.com/articles/xmldocument-xpath-document)